# relation between function and derivatives

Tags: calculus

If there are two non-negative functions $\psi_1(\theta)$ and $\psi_2(\theta)$, for $\theta \in (0, \infty)$, such that $\psi_1(\theta)$ is decreasing, then is is possible to have $\psi_1(\theta) > \psi_2(\theta)$ and $\psi_1'(\theta) < \psi_2'(\theta)$???

Answer (score 0):

$\psi_1(\theta) = 1$

$\psi_2(\theta) = 1 - \frac 1 {\theta}$

Comment: yes...thank you so much

Comment: but is it possible to have $\psi_i, i = 1, 2$ such that $\psi_1(\theta)$ is decreasing, $\frac{\psi_2(\theta)}{\psi_1(\theta)}$ is increasing, $\psi_1(\theta) > \psi_2(\theta)$ and $\psi_1'(\theta) > \psi_2'(\theta)$???

Comment: Oh, probably.  $f > g$ means $g/f < 1$ but increasing while $g$ decreasing.  So $f$ has to be decreasing faster.

Comment: I have been trying to find such functions but not able to get it? do you have any idea that what can be these functions?

Comment: Oh, why not $f(x) = -x$ and $g(x) =-x + 1/x$.  $f'(x)  > g'(x)$ and $f(x)< g(x)$. $g(x) is decreasing and $f(x)/g(x) = 1/1 - 1/x^2$ is increasing?

Comment: thanks but i want $f(x) > g(x)$ and $g(x)/f(x)$ increasing. Also, F and g should be non-negative functions.